# Unexpected behavior using "<count>J" to join multiple lines

Tags: repeated-commands, count

When I prefix the J ("join") command with a count, Vim is joining one fewer line than I expect. For example, with the cursor at the first column, first line of the following,

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

if I type <kbd>J</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> (four J's), I get (as expected):

```
one two three four five
```

But if instead I type <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, I get:

```
one two three four
five
```

It looks like J=1J=2J, 3J=JJ, 4J=JJJ, and so on. Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 7):

After further research and office discussion, I realize this is indeed the expected behavior. According to the vim help:

```
J    Join [count] lines, with a minimum of two lines.
```

I've always thought `[count][command]` was literally another way to type `[command]` repeated `[count]` times. Turns out commands are free to interpret `[count]` as they like, and `J` takes it to mean the number of lines that will be joined; this explains why `1J` and `2J` have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

It is the described behaviour.

`:help J` states

> Join [count] lines, with a minimum of two lines